# Ways to initiate a supernova explosion

Tags: science-fiction, stars, supernova

Assume we have a star that is sufficiently massive to end its life in a supernova. Also, said star is currently fusing heavy enough elements that, under normal progression, it is within less than 200 years from burning iron, causing the actual supernova, what methods could be used to precipitate an immediate or near immediate progression to supernova ignition?

Assume also that you have the ability to manipulate large quantities of mass, energy, and or possibly local universal constants. What would be required? What would be the easiest way to bring about this explosion?

Comment: I've heard Trilithium inhibits nuclear fusion. That ought to do the trick.

Comment: Whatl You guys don't have supernova rounds for your handguns? I thought the second amendment guaranteed that everyone (at least in the US) could cause any nearby star to supernova at any time. 

Comment: Same?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/117319/can-i-trigger-supernova-artificially

Answer (score 1):

Compression, similarly to fusion bombs or nukes.

As you so free with choices, use this one [Muon-catalyzed fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon-catalyzed_fusion)

The goal as usual to create compression shell, for that inject muon as deep as you can, all over the subsurface of the star, to create initial compression blast, by significant and fast increase of fusion reaction.

A wave will compress and collapse the core which then will do the main bang.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has a "science-fiction" tag....

According to the trope-creating *[Children of the Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Lens_(novel))* (1947) by E.E. Smith, creating a supernova can be done by smashing a planet traveling faster-than-light into the desired sun.

Well, folks who have read the book know that when it was tried, using a planet traveling 15 times lightspeed, it created a supernova...and then some.

It was a handy way to obliterate the nefarious denizens of the planet Ploor. The next (and final) battle was even crazier.

Comment: Ploor was taken out by a planet at 15c.  Blasting the star was just to get anyone that might be too far from the planet when it was destroyed.